# Drop Down Menu To The Right

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to make a drop down menu go to the right with HTML and CSS, I have the example here:

`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNLmvq`

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like without the text from codepen.
`http://s22.postimg.org/bd5sc51ap/sidebar.jpg`

If there is any other additional information you need from me, please ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your code but the answer seemed quite clear, not sure if it's what will be the right answer but I've modified it to work for what you've described. If it's not what you're looking for please describe more details about your site needs.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwXjaa

I've changed your aside css to 'float:right' from 'float:left'.

```
aside
{
    float: right;
    width: 164px;
    margin: 12px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-right: thin dashed #2446ff;
    /*background-color: #ff0000;*/
}
```

**update**

I've cleaned up your HTML and re-arranged where the placement of the class 'Schedule' was to be put.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwXjaa

in your HTML I've placed 'Schedule' class onto the li.

CSS now for schedule is as follows:

```
.Schedule ul li{
  display:none;
}
.Schedule:hover > ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:36px;
  left:168px;
  background:blue;
  display:block;

}

.Schedule:hover > ul li {
  position:relative;
  background:blue;
  display:block;

}
```

I've cleared out most of your other CSS you had in there before, wanted to provide you with a clean html/css snippets so you see exactly what you may need to include when you integrate.

What's happening in the above is your 'Schedule' class is on an li, the class is telling all the ul's with li's below that li that has 'Schedule' assigned to it, that they're to display none.

When you hover over schedule, the ul's that the browser finds that are layered under 'Schedule', will display block again and have absolute positioning.

I then made it so that 'Schedule' class on hover of first ul li sets the li's to relative positioning(otherwise all li children will stack ontop of each other  which you don't want) and set display to block so they're visible again.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding but no it isnt what I was looking for. Here is an image to show a drop down menu and the sub menu goes to the right, If you see in my sidebar.jpg image from my original post, I would like to hover over my Schedule button and have sub menus on the right of that. http://icdn6.digitaltrends.com/image/image-37-589x301.png

Comment: do you want the menu to show 'schedule > item1, item2, item3 > SubItem1, SubItem2' ? and ONLY show item1 etc. on hover. While when not hovering you only see 'schedule'? Or do you want it to show 'schedule> item1, item2, item3' then on hover of item3 show submenu items SubItem1 etc.?

Comment: I would like to see Schedule when NOT hovering. When hovering over Schedule, I would still like to see to the right of Schedule like so.

(while hovering) Schedule -> Item1
                                          Item2
                                          Item3

Comment: try looking at it now. when you hover, it will show the items under schedule. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwXjaa  your HTML was a bit broken, the second UL was not closed. Also added new CSS, you'll see the 'aside ul li ul' and 'aside ul li ul:hover' added.

Comment: Ahh its getting there, thank you! And yes youre right about the HTML being a bit broken because I am using images as buttons. Which is probably why its all wacky like that. How can we get the 3 links to appear to the right of SCHEDULE? I am sure we have to add a css code saying right:100% or something along those lines? Can you assist me with that?

Comment: you can take a look at the update now. it shows some list children within the 'schedule' item now to the right side.

Comment: AHH YES!! I will implement this on my project and see how it turns out. I will come back and let you know how it goes! THANK YOU ROG!

Comment: no worries, also for future posts please do provide more in depth information. You are new to stackoverflow and some of the voters can be quite hard on new-comers questions. I am surprised this one didn't get down-voted as it was not as in depth as the community would like to see. For future posts you'll need to show that you did more research and articulate further on your requirements. keep on coding! :)

Comment: HEY RCG, here is a screenshot of what I have. You're right I need to provide more detail & probably all my code so you arent confused. I noticed you changed my html li schedule from "<li> <a" to "<li ". Here is a screenshot of what it looks like so far. http://s11.postimg.org/fp2soot4j/Untitled.jpg Its hard to show on codepen what I have because I am using images as buttons and I cant display that. I didnt want to affect the codepen that you made the code work, however, this codepen is with all the aside section code and the css for the buttons and aside. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwOVda

Comment: one of your problems is you've put '<a class="Schedule">' in your HTML when the class should be applied to the li, not the anchor element. Also your anchor element isn't closed, you open it then open another one within it and close the 2nd one but not the first. In any case you shouldn't have an anchor within an anchor. put the class="Schedule" onto the li element.